# Using Ajax partial view and browser back button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc aapplication, I have a products page which contains a partial view and ajax.beginform. I filter products with ajax begin form. My problem is that when I go to view a different page and then go back to the products page, I lose my filtered page content.

How can I keep my filtered content?
Thanks.

```
 public ActionResult Products(ProductViewModel model, string id)
    {

        int gender=0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            if (id.ToLower()=="kadin")
            {

                gender = 2;
            }
            else if (id.ToLower()=="erkek")
            {
                gender = 1;
            }
            else if (id.ToLower() == "cocuk")
            {
                gender = 3;
            }
        }

        List<Products> list = new List<Domain.Products>();
        if (model.CatList==null)
        {
            list = _service.GetAll();
        }
        else
        {
            list = _service.GetAll().Where(c => model.CatList.Contains(c.CategoryId.ToString())).ToList();
        }

        if (model.prop!=null)
        {
            var proplist = _ppService.GetAll().ToList();
           var proplistt=proplist.Where(x => model.prop.Contains(x.PropertyValueId.ToString())).Select(x => x.ProductId).ToList();
            list = list.Where(p => proplistt.Contains(p.ProductId)).ToList();
        }


        ProductViewModel vm = new ProductViewModel();

        vm.CategoryList = _CategoryService.GetAll().ToList();
        vm.PropertyValuesList = _PropertyValuesService.GetAll().ToList();


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            list = list.Where(x => x.Gender == gender).ToList();
        }
        vm.PropertyInProducts = _ppService.GetAll().ToList();
        vm.PropertyInProducts = _ppService.GetAll().ToList();


        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Order))
            {
                if (model.Order=="01")
                {
                    vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true && x.IsReserved != true) && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductCode)) || ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProductCode)) && x.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(model.ProductCode.ToLower())))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductId).Skip(model.skip).Take(30).ToList();
                }
                else if (model.Order=="02")
                {
                    vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true && x.IsReserved != true) && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductCode)) || ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProductCode)) && x.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(model.ProductCode.ToLower())))).OrderBy(x => x.ProductId).Skip(model.skip).Take(30).ToList();
                }
                else if (model.Order=="03")
                {
                    vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true && x.IsReserved != true) && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductCode)) || ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProductCode)) && x.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(model.ProductCode.ToLower())))).OrderBy(x => x.ProductCode).Skip(model.skip).Take(30).ToList();
                }
                else if (model.Order=="04")
                {
                    vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true && x.IsReserved != true) && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductCode)) || ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProductCode)) && x.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(model.ProductCode.ToLower())))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductCode).Skip(model.skip).Take(30).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true && x.IsReserved != true) && ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductCode)) || ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProductCode)) && x.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(model.ProductCode.ToLower())))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductId).Skip(model.skip).Take(30).ToList();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => (x.IsActive==true && x.IsReserved!=true)&& ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProductCode)) || ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProductCode)) && x.ProductCode.ToLower().Contains(model.ProductCode.ToLower())))).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductId).Skip(model.skip).Take(30).ToList();
            }

            return PartialView("_ProductList",vm);
        }
        else
        {

            vm.ProductList = list.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.IsReserved != true).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProductId).Take(30).ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }


    }




 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Products", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "load", LoadingElementDuration = 50000 }))
        {

            if (lang == "tr-TR")
            {
                           <!--cinsiyet-->
                <div class="FiltreBox">
                    <span class="boxTitle">CİNSİYET</span>
                    <ul class="genderChk">

                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-html="Kadın" name="id" value="kadin" />
                                <span class="Text">Kadın <span></span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-html="Erkek" name="id" value="erkek" />
                                <span class="Text">Erkek <span></span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-html="Çocuk" name="id" value="cocuk" />
                                <span class="Text">Çocuk <span></span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        <!--cinsiyet-->
            }
            else if (lang == "en-gb")
            {
                           <!--cinsiyet-->
                <div class="FiltreBox">
                    <span class="boxTitle">GENDER</span>
                    <ul class="genderChk">

                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-html="Women" class="myCheckbox" name="id" value="kadin" />
                                <span class="Text">Women <span></span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-html="Men" class="myCheckbox" name="id" value="erkek" />
                                <span class="Text">Men <span></span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" data-html="Kids" class="myCheckbox" name="id" value="cocuk" />
                                <span class="Text">Kid <span></span></span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        <!--cinsiyet-->
            }

            if (lang == "tr-TR")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">
                    <span class="boxTitle">KATEGORİ</span>
                    <ul class="categoryChk">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.CategoryName" name="CatList[]" value="@item.CategoryId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.CategoryName</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">
                    <span class="boxTitle">CATEGORY</span>
                    <ul class="categoryChk">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.CategoryList)
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.Description" name="CatList[]" value="@item.CategoryId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.Description</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }

            <!--Kategori-->

        <!--detaylar-->
            if (lang == "tr-TR")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">

                    <span class="boxTitle">DETAYLAR</span>
                    <ul class="propCheck">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyValuesList.Where(x => x.PropertyId == 14))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.PropertyValue" name="prop[]" value="@item.PropertyValueId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.PropertyValue</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
            else if (lang == "en-gb")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">

                    <span class="boxTitle">DETAILS</span>
                    <ul class="propCheck">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyValuesList.Where(x => x.PropertyId == 14))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.PropertyValueEn" name="prop[]" value="@item.PropertyValueId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.PropertyValueEn</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }

        <!--detaylar-->
        <!--gage-->
            if (lang == "tr-TR")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">

                    <span class="boxTitle">GAGE</span>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyValuesList.Where(x => x.PropertyId == 13))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.PropertyValue" name="prop[]" value="@item.PropertyValueId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.PropertyValue</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
            else if(lang=="en-gb")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">

                    <span class="boxTitle">GAGE</span>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyValuesList.Where(x => x.PropertyId == 13))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.PropertyValueEn" name="prop[]" value="@item.PropertyValueId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.PropertyValueEn</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }

        <!--gage-->
        <!--kompozisyon-->
            if (lang == "tr-TR")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">

                    <span class="boxTitle">KOMPOZİSYON</span>
                    <ul class="propCheck">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyValuesList.Where(x => x.PropertyId == 10))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.PropertyValue" name="prop[]" value="@item.PropertyValueId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.PropertyValue</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
            else if(lang=="en-gb")
            {
                <div class="FiltreBox">

                    <span class="boxTitle">COMPOSITION</span>
                    <ul class="propCheck">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.PropertyValuesList.Where(x => x.PropertyId == 10))
                        {
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-html="@item.PropertyValueEn" name="prop[]" value="@item.PropertyValueId" />
                                    <span class="Text">@item.PropertyValueEn</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        }

                    </ul>
                </div>
            }

        <!--kompozisyon-->
            <input type="submit" style="display:none" name="name" id="search" value="Ara" />
        }



    </div>
    <!--Left-->
    <!--right-->

    <div class="RightColums">
        @if (lang == "tr-TR")
        {
            <h1>Tüm Ürünler</h1>
        <!--sıralama-->

            <div class="Shorting">
                <span class="Title">SIRALA : </span>
                <select>
                    <option value="00">Seçin</option>
                    <option value="01">Tarihe Göre Yeni</option>
                    <option value="02">Tarihe Göre Eski</option>
                    <option value="03">Ürün Kodu Yeni</option>
                    <option value="04">Ürün Kodu Eski</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="Search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ara" id="searchh" />
                <a href="javascript:;" id="searchbtn">Ara</a>
            </div>
        }
        else if (lang == "en-gb")
        {
            <h1>All Products</h1>

        <!--sıralama-->
            <div class="Shorting">
                <span class="Title">Order : </span>
                <select id="orderSelect">
                    <option value="00">Select</option>
                    <option value="01">Order By Date Asc</option>
                    <option value="02">Order By Date Desc</option>
                    <option value="03">Order By Product Code Asc</option>
                    <option value="04">Order By Product Code Desc</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="Search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchh" />
                <a href="javascript:;" id="searchbtn">Search</a>
            </div>
        }

        <!--sıralama-->
        <!--Ürünler-->
        <div id="productsList">
            @Html.Partial("_ProductList", Model)

        </div>

        <div id="dataBefore"></div>

        <!--Ürünler-->
        <!--more-->
        <div class="MoreCapsule">
            <span class="Line"></span>
            @if (Model.ProductList.Count() >= 9)
            {
                if (lang == "tr-TR")
                {
                    <a href="javascript:;" id="loadMore">DİĞER ÜRÜNLER</a>

                }
                else if (lang == "en-gb")
                {
                    <a href="javascript:;" id="loadMore">OTHER PRODUCTS</a>

                }
            }
        </div>
        <!--more-->
    </div>



    <!--/right-->
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```
@section PageBottomScripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.selectBox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function () {
            var loadCount = 1;
            $.ugurKonfeksiyonApp.productListPageLoad();
            $(document).on("click", ".removefb", function () {
                var did = $(this).closest("li").data("id");
                if (did!=null) {
                    $('.categoryChk li label span input:checkbox').each(function (index, value) {
                        var cb = $(this);
                        var text = $(this).data("html");
                        var idd = $(this).val();
                        if (did == idd) {
                            cb.click();
                        }

                    });
                }
            else {
                var lId = $(this).closest("li").attr("id");
                $('.propCheck li label span input:checkbox').each(function (index, value) {
                    var cb = $(this);
                    var text = $(this).data("html");
                    var idd = $(this).val();
                    if (lId == idd) {
                        cb.click();
                    }

                });
            }


        });
        $('.categoryChk li label span input:checkbox').each(function (index, value) {
            var text = $(this).data("html");
            var idd = $(this).val();

            $(this).click(function () {
                loadCount = 1;
                $("#search").submit();
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#filterboxx .selected").append('<li data-id="' + idd + '"><a class="removefb" href="#" >x</a>' + text + '</li>');
                }
                else {
                    $("#filterboxx .selected li").each(function (index, value) {
                        if ($(this).data("id") == idd) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }

                    })
                }


            });
        });
        $('.propCheck li label span input:checkbox').each(function (index, value) {
            var text = $(this).data("html");
            var idd = $(this).val();

            $(this).click(function () {
                loadCount = 1;
                $("#search").submit();
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#filterboxx .selected").append('<li id="' + idd + '" ><a href="#" class="removefb">x</a>' + text + '</li>');
                }
                else {
                    $("#filterboxx .selected li").each(function (index, value) {
                        if ($(this).attr("id") == idd) {
                            $(this).hide();
                        }

                    })
                }


            });
        });
        //Every checkboxes in the page
        $('.genderChk li label span input:checkbox').click(function () {
            $('.genderChk li label span input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            $('.genderChk li label span input:checkbox').not(this).closest('span').removeClass("selected");
            $("#search").submit();


        });
        $('.genderChk li label span input:checkbox').each(function () {
            var gender = $(this);
            var gndr = gender.val();
            var text = $(this).data("html");
            if (gndr == '@g') {
                gender.closest("span").addClass("selected");
                gender.attr('checked', true);
                $("#filterboxx .selected").append('<li id="' + gndr + '" ><a href="#" class="removefb">x</a>' + text + '</li>');

            }



        });

        $(function () {
            //var loading = $("#loading");
            $("#loadMore").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //$(document).on({

                //    ajaxStart: function () {
                //        loading.show();
                //    },
                //    ajaxStop: function () {
                //        loading.hide();
                //    }
                //});
                var CatArray = [];
                var prop = [];
                $('.categoryChk li label span input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        CatArray = $(this).val();
                    }
                });
                $('.propCheck li label span input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        prop = $(this).val();
                    }
                });

                var ProductViewModel = {
                    skip: loadCount * 30,
                    id: '@g',
                    CatList: CatArray,
                    prop: prop,
                    Order: $("#orderSelect").val()
                }
                var url ='@Url.Action("Products","Home")';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: ProductViewModel,
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.length !== 0) {
                            //$(data).insertBefore("#dataBefore").fadeIn(100);
                            $("#productsList").append(data);
                        }

                        var ajaxModelCount = data.ModelCount - (loadCount * 30);
                        if (ajaxModelCount <= 0) {
                            $("#loadMore").hide().fadeOut(2000);
                        }
                        $.ugurKonfeksiyonApp.boxStretch();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        //alert("message : \n" +
                        //    "An error occurred, for more info check the js console" +
                        //    "\n status : \n" + status + " \n error : \n" + error);
                    }
                });

                loadCount = loadCount + 1;
            });
        });
        $("#orderSelect").on("change", function () {

            var CatArray = [];
            var prop = [];
            $('.categoryChk li label span input:checkbox').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    CatArray = $(this).val();
                }
            });
            $('.propCheck li label span input:checkbox').each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    prop = $(this).val();
                }
            });

            var ProductViewModel = {
                skip: loadCount * 30,
                id: '@g',
                CatList: CatArray,
                prop: prop,
                Order:$(this).val()
            }
            var url = '@Url.Action("Products","Home")';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: ProductViewModel,
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.length !== 0) {
                        //$(data).insertBefore("#dataBefore").fadeIn(100);
                        $("#productsList").html(data);
                    }

                    var ajaxModelCount = data.ModelCount - (loadCount * 9);
                    if (ajaxModelCount <= 0) {
                        $("#loadMore").hide().fadeOut(2000);
                    }
                    $.ugurKonfeksiyonApp.boxStretch();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    //alert("message : \n" +
                    //    "An error occurred, for more info check the js console" +
                    //    "\n status : \n" + status + " \n error : \n" + error);
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>


<script>
    function load(result) {
        $("#productsList").html(result);
    }
</script>
```

}

Comment: provide any code that you have tried

Comment: i entered action and  razor codes.

Comment: You have to save your filters somewhere, on server or in cookie and on load products list page filter it on start with this saved filters.

Comment: I would store filter information in session variables on the browser and then reference those values when loading the Products page.

Comment: thats ok, i save my filters in session. But how can i know if user press browser back button or user came to products page by another actionlink ? if user came page from another page i have to list products with default fiters if user press browser back button i need previous filters right ?